# Strange behavior when using Completable Future to fetch data from DB using Spring Data

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, completable-future

I noticed one strange behavior when using CompletebleFuture to get data from a Spring Data Repository. The behavior is different using fetching data normally vs using CompletableFuture.

Here is the difference:

> Data retrieved using CompletableFuture

[image: Data retrieved using CompletableFuture]

> Data retrieved normally

[image: Data Retrieved without using CompletableFuture]

My Code looks like this :

[image]

Here my question is why it is unable to fetch the customGroups information when I am using CompletableFuture? Its throwing LazyInitializationException for customGroup fetch. Inside User Entity its defined as Set instead of List and fetchtype- EAGER.

This code is working as expected when calling it normally or synchronously.

Can anyone explain why there is a change in behavior between two ?

Comment: The session is only open in a single thread, with completable future you are using multiple threads and the underlying session (might) not be available anymore to retrieve additional (lazy) data.

Comment: @M.Deinum is there any way to make the session multithreaded?

Comment: how much does it take to search "spring open transaction programmatically" and go from there?

Comment: @Eugene great lead, let me check